# Using custom class with getFieldDecorator (React, Ant Design)

Tags: reactjs, antd

Everything is ok if I use Ant Design TreeSelect component in form like this:

```
<Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator('geo_objects_value', {
        rules: [{
            required: true,
            message: 'Warning msg'
        }],
    })(
        <TreeSelect
            treeData={treeGeoObjects}
            treeNodeFilterProp={'title'}
            treeCheckable={true}
            allowClear
            showCheckedStrategy={SHOW_PARENT}
            dropdownStyle={{maxHeight: 500, overflow: 'auto'}}
        />
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

But if I try to use a custom class with the Ant Design Tree component, it will give a warning message: that means the value has not been received.

My custom class:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.treeData = props.treeData;
        this.state = {
            expandedKeys: [],
            autoExpandParent: true,
            value: [],
        };
    }

    onExpand = expandedKeys => {
        this.setState({
            expandedKeys,
            autoExpandParent: false,
        });
    };

    onCheck = value => {
        this.setState({value});
        this.props.value = value;
        console.log('onCheck', this.props.value);
    };

    renderTreeNodes = data =>
        data.map(item => {
            if (item.children) {
                return (
                    <TreeNode title={item.title} key={item.key} dataRef={item}>
                        {this.renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
                    </TreeNode>
                );
            }
            return <TreeNode key={item.key} {...item} />;
        });

    render() {
        return (
            <Tree
                checkable
                onExpand={this.onExpand}
                expandedKeys={this.state.expandedKeys}
                autoExpandParent={this.state.autoExpandParent}
                onCheck={this.onCheck}
                checkedKeys={this.state.value}
            >
                {this.renderTreeNodes(this.treeData)}
            </Tree>
        );
    }
}
```

Using custom class inside the form:

```
<Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator('geo_objects_value', {
        rules: [{
            required: true,
            message: 'Warning msg'
        }],
    })(
        <Demo treeData={treeGeoObjects}/>
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't getFieldDecorator get the value from my class? Please help!

Answer (score 4):

After initializing a **custom** component with `getFieldDecorator`, the `Form` can't **control** it as it does with default `antd` components.

In this case, the developer needs to use the injected callbacks and manually control the state.

You need to use `this.props.onChange` which injected with `getFieldDecorator`, please [read the docs carefully](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#thispropsformgetFieldDecorator(id,-options)).

> **After wrapped by `getFieldDecorator`**, **value** (or other property defined by valuePropName) **onChange** (or other property defined by trigger) props will be added to form controls, the flow of form data will be handled by `Form`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `Component` (or `PureComponent`).
2. Make sure the controlled value has the same name as the `valuePropName`.
3. Create a function that is triggered by `onChange`. This function will not only update the controlled value, but it will also trigger the controlled onChange handler.

```js
class MyInput extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const value = props.value || {};
    this.state = {
      // Same name as valuePropName in getFieldDecorator ('value' is default):
      // https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#getFieldDecorator(id,-options)-parameters
      value,
      // ...
    };
  }

  handleChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    if (onChange) {
      // This will provide the form with changes
      onChange({ ...this.state, ...{ value } });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <Input
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```